# Excel2016VBA (Mac) MkDir returns error 75

Tags: excel, macos, vba, mkdir

I've been working on a simple code (with guidance from the internet) that makes a directory based on what's in cell R1C1.

```
Sub mkdirtest()

Dim f_string As String
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
f_string = Cells(1, 1)

MkDir (f_string)

End Sub
```

In R1C1 I have for example "/Users/cwu/Desktop/Tefdshsdfh" and running the macro, I get a dialog to grant file access (for which I choose desktop and then select grant access) and then

```
Run-time error '75':
Path/File access error
```

However everything works when I have "/Users/cwu/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/EXCELtest/Tefdshsdfh" in R1C1 which is a folder in a location that "bypasses" the Apple sandbox/security measures (from this site http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac034.htm forgive me for any wrong lingo, I'm new to coding.).

Is there a solution to this? I've read that Excel for Mac 2016 has issues and is being worked on by Microsoft. The code also works fine in 2011, which I've tested the code in.

Comment: Doesn't Mac use a different path separator than Windows?

Comment: Use `Application.PathSeparator` instead of "\" or ":"   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820973.aspx   **Edit:** on re-reading the question this is likely not your problem...

Comment: Sorry mate, but any VBA on a mac has issues. VBA has less power on macs and sometimes stuff that is simple on win is impossible on mac.

Comment: Thanks for the tries so far, but the code works fine in certain directories so I believe the path separators aren't a concern - it seems to have something to do with security measures in office for mac 2016 or similar... works fine in 2011 as I said

Answer (score 0):

On Mac or Windows, that error will be generated if there is a legitimate error, either the path length is too long, the folder you are trying to create has illegal characters, or there are security restrictions preventing you from creating a folder at that location.

However, it will also return that error if the directory already exists, I don't want to sound patronising, but could this be your issue?

Comment: Not patronizing at all. Although, the directory definitely isn't there when I execute the code. Since it makes the folder I check that it isn't there before I run it.